# get container's name from shared directory

Tags: bash, docker

Currently I am running docker with more than 15 containers with various apps. I am exactly at the point that I am getting sick and tired of looking into my docs every time the command I used to create the container. Trying to create scripts and alias commands to get this procedure easier I encountered this problem:

*Is there a way to get the container's name from the host's shared folder?*

For example, I have a directory "MyApp" and inside this I start a container with a shared folder "shared". It would be perfect if:
**a.** I had a global script somewhere and an alias command set respectively and
**b.** I could just run something like "startit"/"stopit"/"rmit" from any of my "OneOfMyApps" directory and its subdirectories. I would like to skip `docker ps`-> Cp -> etc etc every time, and just get the container's name from the script. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into docker compose?

Comment: @Mad Wombat I don't understand what do you mean by that. Yes, some of my containers are also started with docker compose.

Comment: Well, looking at your question and it seems like what you want is to have all your container configs aggregated in one file and have one command that will start all your containers in just the right way. And that is pretty much what docker compose does. You can specify container names in the compose config. Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: Not quite that. I have shared directories for each one of my app. When I am working on the files in the directories, it would be great if I could just run "start this" like a global alias command that would call a script to do what it is to do. Which will require the name of the container at some point.

Comment: You want to use the name of the container in a script that you run from inside the container?

Comment: No, the script is running outside of the container. I want to get the name when I run a script from outside the container, in the shared directory

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution would be to use environment variables to pass the name into the container and use some pre-determined file in the volume to store the name. So, you would create the container with -e flag

`docker create --name myapp -e NAME=myapp myappimage`

And inside the image entry point script you would have something like

`cd /shared/volume
echo $NAME >> .containers`

And in your shell script you would do something like

```
function stopit() {
    for name in `cat .containers`; do
        docker stop $name;
    done;
}
```

But this is a bit fragile. If you are going to script the commands anyway, I would suggest using `docker ps` to get a list of containers and then using `docker inspect` to find which ones use this particular shared volume. You can do all of it inside the script, so what is the problem.